# making new symbol from two symbols

Tags: symbols

I would like to make a new math symbol from overlapping two symbols, such as `$\nabla\kern-7.5pt\nabla$`. The problem is that the symbol spacing is altered depending on the line, often to the point where the overlap is not recognisable. From looking at other replies I understand that fixing this is likely to do with adding box commands, but there are so many of these that I am not sure where to start! Any help appreciated (I am obviously not an expert ...)

Comment: Are you using the new symbol in math formulas? What should it denote?

Comment: Yes, it is an operator, a variant of nabla for a derivative

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would use `\mkern` instead of `\kern`, because it uses unit `mu`, which follows the math style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\doublenabla}{%
  {\nabla\mkern-12mu\nabla}% subformula acts as \mathord
}
\begin{document}
\[ \doublenabla_{\doublenabla_{\doublenabla}} \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Adjust the shift value to your needs.

Comment: Tried it and it looks good - thanks

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility using `mathtools` to specify the offset from the left rather than from the right produces slightly different spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\nnabla}{\mathrlap{\nabla}\,\nabla}
\begin{document}
$\nnabla_{\nnabla_{\nnabla}}$
\end{document}
```

[image: double nablas]